# Restore In App Purchases on New Devices / Deleted Apps on the same device using restoreCompletedTransactions

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, restore

I have an app in the App Store and I'm bringing `IAPs` to unlock features in the new version. I have implemented the IAP mechanism for two Non-Consumable products and all purchases are working well.

When the user purchases a product, I set a `NSUserDefault` flag to then use that to unlock features elsewhere in the app.

That works well for me.

My question though is around restoring.

I have seen lots of questions on this but it's not quite clear to me what the solution is.

If the user purchases the IAP, it stores the `NSUserDefault` flag. However, if the user uses a different device with the same Apple ID, or deletes and reinstalls the app, the restore purchase button doesn't detect the previously saved `NSUserDefault` (understandably).

```
- (void)restoreThePurchase
{
    // Similar to the purchase
    // Ask the App Store to restore rather than create a payment. We call it via the SKPaymentQueue.
    // When we've sent that ot the App Store, the App Store will get back to the App Delegate and get back to the paymentQueue updated:Transactions to the restore.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

I have three classes:

- `IAPViewController` which contains the purchase and restore `UIButton`
- `e100EntriesPurchase` which contains the IAP methods like make a purchase and restore.
- `eUnlimitedEntriesPurchase` which contains the IAP methods for the unlimited purchase along with the make purchase and restore.

When the restore button is pressed, I check which IAP the device had and then call the appropriate restore method.

```
- (IBAction)iapRestorePurchaseButton:(id)sender
{
    // When the restorePurchase button is tapped, we will run a few tests.

    if (([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FullVersion100Entries"]) && (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FullVersionUnlimitedEntries"]))

    {
        [self.e100EntriesPurchase restoreThePurchase];
        NSLog(@"100 yes but unlmited no restore!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    else if ((![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FullVersion100Entries"]) && ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FullVersionUnlimitedEntries"]))
    {
        [self.eUnlimitedEntriesPurchase restoreThePurchase];


    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore Unsuccessful" message:@"Your Apple ID doesn't have an active purchase for upgrading to Pro. " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}
```

So I'm facing the `UIAlertView` when I delete and reinstall the App because the NSUserDefaults will not be set to anything.

I'm not sure how exactly to do this, but I suspect when I make the purchase, I'll have to make more than just a `NSUserDefault` and need to save some sort of receipt?

Any guidance on this issue would really be helpful.

Comment: What kind of product are you selling? It looks as though it's a consumable from your code?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that to the question and I'll update it now. Non-consumable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user taps "Restore purchase" button you should just do:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

New transactions will be pushed to your payment queue with state "restored" and app should treat them as any new purchased transaction.

Comment: Dear Mikhail - as you said that, I removed the UIAlertView (which indicated there's no successful restores available) and waited and it did actually run through and restore. I understand now that the reason the UIAlertView was being set is because at that point, the NSUserDefaults ARE indeed null. Thanks so much for your thoughts on this because my code was running the same method, just called from the other class, but your answer helped me think straight :)